# Truck won't start after cold snap even with new battery

Tags: starting, dodge, cranks-wont-run, ram

I tried to start a 06 Dodge Ram when it was very cold. It did not start, then tried 2 days later and it still won't start even with the new battery. What could be going on?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Can you describe what you see and hear when you try to start it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.